# Как научить бота отвечать в беседе вк?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть vk_api, где все функции записаны, и есть обработчик, bot.php
В нем прописано:

```
if ($data->type == 'message_new') {

if ($message == '!расписание') {

        $vk->sendMessage($id, "Привет, вот расписание на сегодня");
        $vk->sendImage($id, __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/schedule.jpeg');

    }


}
```

В vk_api.php такой код:

```
    public function sendMessage($sendID,$message){
    if ($sendID != 0 and $sendID != '0') {
        return $this->request('messages.send',array('message'=>$message, 'peer_id'=>$sendID));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Что нужно написать и как создать функцию, которая скажет боту, что нужно отвечать в чат (беседу вк), а не в личные сообщения (Если в беседе дать доступ к всем сообщениям, бот видит, не читает, но отвечает в ЛС тому, кто ввел команду)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас бот работает на CallbackAPI, то у присланного в формате JSON запроса есть запись **peer_id** - именно в ней указан ID, откуда пришел запрос, в записи from_id - ID пользователя.

```
if ($data->type == 'message_new') 
{
    $id = $data->object->peer_id;
    if ($message == '!расписание') 
    {
       $vk->sendMessage($id, "Привет, вот расписание на сегодня");
       $vk->sendImage($id, __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/schedule.jpeg');
    }
 }
```

Попробуйте так